# How to delete a row in a grid in C# windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have started developing a windows phone application where I'm creating the row in a grid dynamically. Upon some conditions I need to the delete the row and all its content in that row.

Here is my sample code.

```
        result = e.Parameter as string;          
        string[] acst = result.Split('|');
        int j = 0;
        root2.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(10) });
        for (int i = 6; i < acst.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            TextBlock mytextblock = new TextBlock();
            mytextblock.Name = "txtDetails" + root2.Children.Count + 1;
            mytextblock.Text = acst[i + 1];
            if (mytextblock.Text != "")
            {
                if (mytextblock.Text.Trim() != "0.00") // if result is 0.00 then i have to delete all the content in that row.
                {
                    if (j == 0)
                    {

                            mytextblock.FontSize = 14;
                            mytextblock.IsTextScaleFactorEnabled = false;
                            mytextblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                            mytextblock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                            Grid.SetColumn(mytextblock, 1);
                            Grid.SetRow(mytextblock, (i) / 6);
                            j++;

                    }
                    else if (j == 1)
                    {

                            mytextblock.FontSize = 14;
                            mytextblock.IsTextScaleFactorEnabled = false;
                            mytextblock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                            mytextblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                            mytextblock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                            Grid.SetColumn(mytextblock, 2);
                            Grid.SetRow(mytextblock, (i) / 6);
                            j++;

                    }
                    else if (j == 2)
                    {

                            mytextblock.FontSize = 14;
                            mytextblock.IsTextScaleFactorEnabled = false;
                            mytextblock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                            mytextblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                            mytextblock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                            Grid.SetColumn(mytextblock, 3);
                            Grid.SetRow(mytextblock, (i) / 6);
                            j=0;
            root2.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(60) });

                    }                            
                }

                    root2.Children.Add(mytextblock);
            }
                else
                {

                    root2.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt((i / 6)); // here I'm getting Arugument Exception
                }
            }
```

for example if I get mytextblock.text = 0.00 in third column (j=2  in this case). i need to remove the content in column 1 and 2  or to delete thst particular row.

I've tried "root2.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt" but there I am getting Arugument Exception. Where I'm missing?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Initially your grid has 1 row you are creating whose index is 0. But when you are executing 
 `root2.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt((i / 6));`
actually you are getting 
`root2.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(1);`
So you should use 
`root2.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt((i / 6)-1);` would solve the exception

To answer the second question the code is too much confusing. I am listing some

```
1: Why are you starting loop from 6
2: Why dividing i/6
3: What exactly you are getting from result
```

Comment: Great. Now I'm getting result without exception. but the column containing 0.00 in a row  alone is removed. I need the entire row to be deleted. How to achieve this.